# I'm looking for a descriptive word for someone who only sees things the way they want to see them

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that refers to someone who only sees things the way they want to see them.

"She just can't seem to take someone else's view into account. She's very ____."

Something along those lines.

Comment: Please, include an example sentence with a blank space showing how you would like the word you're looking for to be used. Otherwise, the question appears to be too broad to get a specific answer.

Comment: Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered.

Comment: ... she's very self-centered / blinkered.

Comment: "Inconsiderate" could be a fit. It's not exactly what you asked, as it has more implications, but someone who is incosiderate is acting in a way that isn't taking other people's welfare into account. It shows either lack of seeing the other person's perspective, which is what you asked for, or it shows a lack of care for the other person's welfare. So, it is not exactly what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

As in:

"She just can't seem to take someone else's view into account. She's very **closed-minded**."

**closed-minded**   [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/closed-minded)

adj.

> Intolerant of the beliefs and opinions of others; stubbornly
>   unreceptive to new ideas.

Comment: Did you intentionally put *close-minded* in one line & *close**d**-minded* in the other place.  I note that TFD gives one as a variant of the other, but that wan't clear ot me from your answer.

Comment: @TrevorD my mistake ... ty

Answer (score 0):

According to [MW Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/narrow-minded):

> **narrow-minded:** unwilling to grant other people social rights or to accept other viewpoints

Answer (score 0):

One such word is ***opinionated*** implying that someone is having a rather fixed opinion (on something).

> "She just can't seem to take someone else's view into account. She's
>   very ***opinionated***."

M-W:

> **[opinionated](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/opinionated)** *adjective*
>
> : firmly or unduly adhering to one's own opinion or to preconceived
>   notions
>   … focus groups, which tend to be dominated by the loudest and
>   most opinionated people … — James Surowiecki

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the term "Pareidolia" is what you are looking for.

> : the tendency to perceive a specific, often meaningful image in a random or ambiguous visual pattern

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pareidolia)

Comment: You should add a dictionary definition and the reason why you think this is the word.

Answer (score 0):

"OBTUSE" would work I think if I'm grasping the context.